# How to call service function in a controller with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a function from a service in a controller but I get an error saying that the thing I'm calling isn't a function. I'm new to AngularJS so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. So, what's the correct way to call a service function in a controller?

I'm trying to call `getCurrentUserInfo` in the `ProfileCtrl`

```
.service('AuthService', function($http, Backand){    
    function getCurrentUserInfo() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + "users",
            params: {
                filter: JSON.stringify([{
                    fieldName: "email",
                    operator: "contains",
                    value: self.currentUser.name
                }])
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data && response.data.data && response.data.data.length == 1)
                return response.data.data[0];
        });
    }
})

.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', 'AuthService', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, AuthService) {

  AuthService.getCurrentUserInfo().then(function(response){
   $scope.user = response.data.data;
});

//  function getCurrentUserInfo() {
//    AuthService.getCurrentUserInfo()
//    .then(function (result) {
//      $scope.user = result.data;
//    });
//  }

}])
```

Comment: did you include all the js files in your index.html page?

Comment: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make it a property of `this`.

```
   .service('AuthService', function($http, Backand){    
        this.getCurrentUserInfo = function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: baseUrl + "users",
                params: {
                    filter: JSON.stringify([{
                        fieldName: "email",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: self.currentUser.name
                    }])
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data && response.data.data && response.data.data.length == 1)
                    return response.data.data[0];
            });
        }
    })
```

Then in your controller

```
AuthService.getCurrentUserInfo(whatEverYourParamsAre)
```

Edit: Actually, let me provide a little bit of context. Angular applies the `new` function to every `.service(....)` you include in your controller. As we know, calling this.aFunction in a constructor function causes the `new` operator in javascript to treat the `aFunction` function as a property on the object your constructor returns.